# print a hollow square using list comprehensions?

Tags: python, nested-loops

Trying to get the hollow square example done using list comprehensions ...

```
side = int(input())
for i in range(side):
    for j in range(side):
        print('*' if(i == 0 or i == side - 1 or j == 0 or j == side - 1) else ' ', end='')
    print()
```

my goal is to have the nested loop also in the comprehension format but can't figure it out.

tried it like this.. but it prints out each side of the square in a one line...

```
side = int(input())
square= ["*" if (i == 0 or i == side - 1 or j == 0 or j == side - 1) else " " for i in range(side) for j in range(side)]
print(''.join(square),end='')
```

Comment: You have a `print` at the end of the outer loop which is putting the newlines between rows of stars. You need some way to handle this newline in your comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

you could do it like this:

```
side = 5

s = "\n".join("*"+c*(side-2)+"*" for c in f"*{'*':>{side-1}}")

print(s)
*****
*   *
*   *
*   *
*****
```

or let the print function provide the end of lines:

```
s = ["*"+c*(side-2)+"*" for c in f"*{'*':>{side-1}}"]

print(*s,sep="\n")
*****
*   *
*   *
*   *
*****
```

Could be also done with the comprehension inside the print call:

```
side = 5

s = f"*{'*':>{side-1}}"
print(*(s.replace(' ',c) for c in s),sep="\n")

*****
*   *
*   *
*   *
*****
```

or

```
print(*("*"+"* "[i%(n-1)>0]*(side-2)+"*" for i in range(side)),sep="\n")
*****
*   *
*   *
*   *
*****
```

If you need to use nested comprehensions, you could do this:

```
s = [["*" if {r,c}&{0,side-1} else " " for c in range(side)]
     for r in range(side)]

print(*map(''.join,s),sep="\n")
*****
*   *
*   *
*   *
*****
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
side = int(input())
s = ''.join(['{}{}'.format('*' if (i == 0 or i == side - 1 or j == 0 or j == side - 1) else ' ', '\n' if j == side - 1 else '') for i in range(side) for j in range(side)])
print(s)
```

This uses `format()` to output a possible `\n` if we've reached the end of a row. Format in this case works like `"{}{}".format('hey', '123') --> "hey123"`. You could probably just append the two strings but this looks nicer IMO. The first `{}` in format is for the `*` or  , the second `{}` is either empty `''` or a newline `\n`. This makes it print properly.

Cool?

Comment: Very cool !! is that why you splitted the if statement last part  ? "\n' if j == side - 1 else "

Comment: yeah that's the part that determines whether to place a \n or not into the second {}. be sure to mark an answer as correct ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Using nested list comprehension:

```
side = int(input())
square = ''.join([''.join(["*" if (i * j == 0 or i == side - 1 or j == side - 1) else " " for i in range(side)]) + '\n' for j in range(side)])
print(square)
```

Prints:

```
5
*****
*   *
*   *
*   *
*****
```